# dplyr and group_by: factor vs no factor

Tags: r, dplyr

(**The described behaviour was a bug!**)

I do not understand the effect of `group_by` on columns that are a factor and that are not. The following analyses both possibilities:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(value=seq(1,10), height=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

# height is no factor
dfs <- df %>% group_by(height) %>% summarize(m=mean(value))
dfs$height==dfs$height[1]

# height is factor
df$height <- as.factor(df$height)
dfs <- df %>% group_by(height) %>% summarize(m=mean(value))
```

Here, a data frame

```
   value height
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      1
4      4      1
5      5      1
6      6      2
7      7      2
8      8      2
9      9      2
10    10      2
```

Is summarized by height. When `df$height` is not a factor, the results looks like this:

```
  height        m
1      1 4.500000
2      1 3.000000
3      1 2.000000
4      1 1.000000
5      2 9.000000
6      2 6.000000
7      2 8.333333
```

while if `df$height` is a factor, the result is what I want:

```
  height m
1      1 3
2      2 8
```

Why does something like this happen? My first guess was that it is a numerical issue and non-factor `height`s differ very slightly. However, the test above shows that all `height==1` are equal:

```
> dfs$height==dfs$height[1]
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Well, ok, I could just use the factor but with that I loose the numerical character of the height. For example, I would like to sort by height or choose the highest height.

Comment: I can't reproduce, are you using the latest version of `dplyr` - 0.2?

Comment: @James I use the most recent version 0.2 but with `R` 3.0.3. On another machine with `R` 3.1.0, I cannot reproduce it either. I will test a more recent `R` on the first machine.

Comment: @James The problem still exists on one machine with `R` 3.1.0. So the issue must come from deeper components. The software is rather old (e.g. gcc 4.3.2). In general, should the first version without factor work? Or does it depend on the machine?

Comment: It's very strange. The only thing I can think of is that the height variable values are close to 1 but differ slightly due to numerical precision errors during their calculation. Why it is happening on one machine but not the other might be due to how such numerical errors are handled. Here is a reproducible example data.frame: `x <- data.frame(value=1:3,height=c(0.3,0.1+0.2,0.4))`

Comment: @James I also thought of that so I did the equality test in `R` above. Apparently, the heights are equal on the `R` level but not in the `C++` routines that `dplyr` also uses. Your example shows nicely that is probably not a good idea to use float values in `group_by`. The conversion of the heights with `as.factor` seems to check for small numerical differences so the same level is applied to `0.3` and `0.1+0.2`.

Comment: You could also try using `round` on your data to eliminate any precision artefacts.

Comment: @James That would not solve the main issue from above, would it? On `R` level, all heights `1` are already equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56761/discussion-between-james-and-sebschub).

Comment: I created a [bug report on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/482) but Hadley was not able to reproduce it. It seems to be system dependent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of `group_by`, it works on any variable type, not just factors. Based on https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/482 and my own attempts to reproduce, this issue should be closed.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour was a bug.

Comment: Why am I still getting the following error message then: 'Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"' (I updated all packages and R version)